# Two state switch using transistor (bi-directional)

Tags: transistors, switches, relay, circuit-design, solid-state-relay

I have an existing pair of wires driving a servo motor. One of them is +12V, the other one 0V. Depending on the rotation direction of the motor, the voltage flips.

I now want to put an optional section in between (see below). The pins A,B,C,D basically lead to a arduino that can manually control the servo.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwImrR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The question is: How can I design the switches, so that they can be switched by the arduino?
Usually, I could use a relay. However, my circuit should be as small as possible and the relays are quite big.

Is it also possible to realize this function with transistors? The problem hereby might be that the circuit must not produce a lot of heat, because the board is going to be in a small air-tight case. Therefore SSR's also might not be a good idea ...

Can someone with a little expertise help me?

I'm pretty new to circuit design, so sorry if this question might seem a little straight forward.

---

Edit:
Would this also work with a spdt mosfet relay?

Comment: It's called an H bridge to switch high currents at some voltage in either direction. Usually the top side drivers control direction , while low side controls PWM V avg.   Shopping for such a motor or servo controller is lower cost than DIY and not an entry level task.

Comment: Depending on the relays you use, they will wear out. The "H" bridge mentioned by Sunnyskyguy EE75 is a better way to go...

Comment: The question is not clear.  The drawing implies that a 12 V *power* source goes through the switches to the servo, but you say that ABCD are *signals* from an arduino.  Starting at the left, are the two wires between the servo and SW1 carrying power, or control signals?

Comment: @AnalogKid Sorry, it was meant to be 12V in the text. I corrected it now.
There are only power wires in the drawing. By 'lead to the arduino', I did not mean a direct connection, but rather an indirect connection using for instance a transistor.

Comment: A H bridge might solve my problem, thanks @SunnyskyguyEE75. I was looking at http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/l293d.pdf. Do these IC's develop a lot of heat? And since the 12V / 0V wires can switch: are H bridges accessible in both ways (as relays are)?

Comment: L293 are very lossy and thus get hot, you would need a FET H bridge with deadtime to prevent shoot thru across supply rails with RdsOn much lower than servo motor DCR.

Comment: You do not need SW2 - just connect 0 & 12 to the Arduino circuit and to SW1 and ignore the 12V when Arduino operation is not needed.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I do need SW2, since the arduino needs to monitor the voltage at pins C and D while giving output at A and B.

Comment: @PH223 No! - probably :-). You can monitor C&D WITHOUT a switch. Just connect them always and monitor them when desired.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon True that - thanks! But it still leaves the question of how to implement the other switch. Could a DPDT mosfet relay be the solution?

Comment: What currents are involved? Relays can be small - especially if used for changeover switching only. More crucial (probably) is HOW do you implement the servo control from AB? Presumably the servo requires a full range of currents from AB and polarity may reverse. Yes & yes?

Comment: I assume that the current through the servo is around 0.5-0.7 amps. I would not mind using a relay as long as it's small. The control of the servo via AB is not a problem, since I already have a working circuit for that.
Do you have any particular recommendation for a relay?

Comment: Still could not find a suitable device. Does anyone know one?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, an H-bridge driver with four external power MOSFETs will give you an all-electronic motor reverser that needs only one control line from the Arduino (two if you want a third state - off).  The larger the MOSFETs, the lower the heat.  International Rectifier is big in h-bridge control chips.

Here is the general idea:

[image: H-Bridge concept]

Comment: OK, that looks good. But this does not look like it can replace a bi-directional switch.
My basic problem is not the reverse driving of the motor. I just need help in realizing the two-way switch, which needs to support current-flow in both directions.